# GWT-P, GWT-PLATFORM, REST, EJB 3.1 login page,user session

Tags: session, authentication, ejb

I want to have got the login page in my GWTP project.
I have got the login and password in my presenter. I can use REST or RPC communication with server side to check login+password. In server side i am using EJB. Simple example how write ejb to start session and check login+password and what i should to do i my RPC/REST:

```
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you mean to use [Rest-Dispatch](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/communication/index.html) on a `LoginPresenter` to call your EJB login endpoint? I suggest you read this [article](http://blog.arcbees.com/2015/10/27/gwtp-beginners-tutorial-toaster-launcher-part-2/#RestDispatch) section on how to use Rest-Dispatch. You should implement the `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()` methods but really you can do want you want with these methods. `onSuccess()` can point to a new Presenter using the `PlaceManager` and you could log the exception on `onFailure()`.